# Access 2003: run code on database close

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

In Access 2003, there are ways of running code when a form or database is opened, but what about when the database is closed?

My motivation is the unavoidable use of a somewhat buggy third-party COM library. Releasing the COM reference (by setting the variable to Nothing) causes it (correctly) to disconnect from its server. The trouble is it can't then re-connect without exiting the process and starting a new one (which is a known bug). In this case, the process is the whole Access IDE :(

Ideally I'd like to store the COM reference somewhere that would be protected from the VBA "Reset" action which clears global variables (and is common during debugging, sometimes forced by a code edit). But then I would like to have the chance to clean up before the database is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run code at database close if you have a form which you set to automatically open at database startup ... and leave the form open.  Then you can use the form's On Close event to run your cleanup code:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
    'do your stuff here '
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Good idea. Now how do I call AddRef from VBA (it gives an error), and cast the COM reference to an integer in order to store it?

Comment: Never mind, I've posted a whole new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836046/access-hidden-form-method-to-store-a-com-reference

Answer (score 0):

don't release the reference.  Let Access do that when it closes.

Comment: But I want to do some cleanup just *before* Access (or the DB) closes. Access won't do it for me.

Comment: you mean cleanup using your buggy COM library?  don't do it within an Access session, wait until they quit Access.

Comment: I'm calling the COM library from Access VBA. I want to do the clean up the same way.

Comment: I would never want to depend on VBA to release external references. I'd want to clear them all myself when my app exits. The usual approach is to have a hidden form whose OnClose event calls the teardown code.